# Key-value pairs in SQL table

Tags: sql, django, django-models, database-design

I am building a Django app and I would like to show some statistics on the main page, like total number of transactions, percentage of successful transactions, daily number of active users etc.

I don't want to calculate these values in the view every time a user requests the main page for performance reasons. I thought of 2 possible solutions.

**(1) Create a number of one-record tables**

Create a table for each of the statistics, e.g.:

```
from django.db import models

class LastSuccessfulTransactionDate(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()

class TotalTransactionAmount(models.Model):
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

# ...
```

and make sure that only one record exists in each table.

**(2) Create a table with key-value data**

```
class Statistics(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.TextField()
```

and save the data by doing:

```
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal
import pickle

statistics = {
    'last_successful_transaction_date': datetime(2010, 2, 3),
    'total_transaction_amount': Decimal('1234.56'),
}
for k, v in statistics.items():
    try:
        s = Statistics.objects.get(key=k)
    except Statistics.DoesNotExist:
        s = Statistics(key=k)
    s.value = base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(v, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)).decode()
    s.save()
```

and retrieve by:

```
for s in Statistics.objects.all():
    k = s.key
    v = pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(s.value.encode()))
    print(k, v)
```

In both cases the data would be updated every now and then by a cron job (they don't have to be very acurate).

To me solution (2) looks better, because to display the main page I would need to get data from the `Statistics` table only, not from a number of one-record tables. Is there any recommended solution to this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is even better solution if you are using Postgresql, which is [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield). You can directly store the key value pair in the JSONField. Try like this:

```
# model
class Statistics(models.Model):
    records = JSONField()

# usage
statistics = {
    'last_successful_transaction_date': datetime(2010, 2, 3),
    'total_transaction_amount': Decimal('1234.56'),
}

Statistics.objects.create(records=statistics)

Statistics.objects.filter(records__last_successful_transaction_date= datetime(2010, 2, 3))  # Running query

s = Statistics.objects.filter(records__last_successful_transaction_date= datetime(2010, 2, 3)).first()
new_statistics = {
    'last_successful_transaction_date': datetime(2012, 2, 3),
    'total_transaction_amount': Decimal('1234.50'),
}
records = s.records
records.update(new_statistics)
s.records = records
s.save()
```

Comment: Well, depends how you want to use it. I would suggest to create new entry for each statistical data. But if you want keep everything in same database row, then please see my updated answer

Comment: This looks good, easier than pickling and encoding/decoding, thanks.